# Javascript: getFullyear() is not a function

Tags: javascript, date

I am getting an error:

```
Statdate.getFullyear() is not a function.
```

From this javascript code:

```
var start = new Date();
start = document.getElementById('Stardate').value ;

var y = start.getFullYear();
```

Any idea why that function isn't available?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Try this...

```
 var start = new Date(document.getElementById('Stardate').value);
 var y = start.getFullYear();
```

Comment: for those who search for "getFullyear() is not a function" , this kind of error some times happened when you use "let" keyword instead of "var" to declare the date object

Comment: @adhamdwikat Can you explain how/why? In what circumstances can this occur due to let/var?

Answer (score 70):

One way to get this error is to forget to use the 'new' keyword when instantiating your Date in javascript like this:

```
> d = Date();
'Tue Mar 15 2016 20:05:53 GMT-0400 (EDT)'
> typeof(d);
'string'
> d.getFullYear();
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Had you used the 'new' keyword, it would have looked like this:

```
> el@defiant $ node
> d = new Date();
Tue Mar 15 2016 20:08:58 GMT-0400 (EDT)
> typeof(d);
'object'
> d.getFullYear(0);
2016
```

Another way to get that error is to accidentally re-instantiate a variable in javascript between when you set it and when you use it, like this:

```
el@defiant $ node
> d = new Date();
Tue Mar 15 2016 20:12:13 GMT-0400 (EDT)
> d.getFullYear();
2016
> d = 57 + 23;
80
> d.getFullYear();
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Answer (score 27):

You are overwriting the `start` date object with the `value` of a DOM Element with an id of `Startdate`.

This should work:

```
var start = new Date(document.getElementById('Stardate').value);

var y = start.getFullYear();
```

Answer (score 4):

All the above answers are correct. I just want to highlight one thing that I was doing wrong.

When creating a date object I was using `new date().toISOString()` which was the main reason that it was throwing this error.

So dont change your date object in a local string format if you are applying `date.getFullYear()`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got the error when trying to access the Date property of an object. This was throwing the error date.getFullyear() is not a function.

```
if (msg.date).getFullYear() == 2023){
```

After the change below it worked fine

```
if (new Date(msg.date).getFullYear() == 2023){
```