# Format date to MM/dd/yyyy in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dateformat like this `'2010-10-11T00:00:00+05:30'`. I have to format in to `MM/dd/yyyy` using JavaScript or jQuery . Anyone help me to do the same.

Comment: How is this a duplicate, one guy asks where the documentation is, the other how to format a date into a specific format... ?

Comment: not sure why everyone always adds strings together for this rather than use `toLocaleDateString` which is less jenky: `function getDate(str) {var ops = {year: 'numeric'}; ops.month = ops.day = '2-digit'; return new Date(str).toLocaleDateString(0, ops);}`

Comment: @omikes I was not able to make your function work `var testGetDate = getDate('2010-10-11T00:00:00+05:30');` on ServiceNow platform.  Not sure why, but it works on jsconsole.com

Comment: The correct solution nowadays is to use the `Intl.DateTimeFormat` API

Comment: Yes, agreed, e.g., `new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format(date)` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat

Answer (score 314, accepted):

Try this; bear in mind that JavaScript months are 0-indexed, whilst days are 1-indexed.

```js
var date = new Date('2010-10-11T00:00:00+05:30');
    alert(((date.getMonth() > 8) ? (date.getMonth() + 1) : ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1))) + '/' + ((date.getDate() > 9) ? date.getDate() : ('0' + date.getDate())) + '/' + date.getFullYear());
```

Comment: edited above to account for the fact that javascript months are zero based...you must always add one to the month to get the exact month when displaying the data to a user.

Comment: that's not actually MM/dd/yyyy.  That's M/d/yyyy.   Does your date need leading zeros?

Comment: If using angular, you may want to consider: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: This answer is wrong. See my answer below.

Comment: Really consider using a library like Moment.js. It will format in desired result :)

Comment: Agree this answer is not correct. It does not produce mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: why we have to add +1 in .getMonth() and not in other? i was suppose to add 90 days to current date, so date and year is getting calculated fine but not the month. I have to add +1 in getMonth, why so ?

Comment: Correct answer should be var result = ((date.getMonth().toString().length > 1) ? (date.getMonth() + 1) : ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1))) + '/' + ((date.getDate().toString().length > 1) ? date.getDate() : ('0' + date.getDate())) + '/' + date.getFullYear()

Comment: @AkshayChawla You have to add `1` to `date.getMonth()` because Jan is `0`

Comment: Is there any JS method available to convert into specific date format

Comment: There is no need for a Date object, and this doesn't produce the required format and may well return different day, month and year values depending on the timezone it's run in.

Comment: See my answer below, which is also updated to ES2019

Comment: @JyotirmayaPrusty no it's not. `10` will become `010`

Comment: This happened to me, I solved it using this:
var date = new Date('2010-10-11T00:00:00+05:30');
var month = ("0"+(date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
var day = ("0"+(date.getDate())).slice(-2);
alert(month + '/' + day + '/' +  date.getFullYear());

Comment: The correct answer will be : var result = ((date.getMonth() > 8) ? (date.getMonth() + 1) : ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1))) + '/' + ((date.getDate() > 9) ? date.getDate() : ('0' + date.getDate())) + '/' + date.getFullYear(); This way we can reduce toString and length function calls. Also, the condition date.getMonth().toString().length > 1 will give wrong result as 010 for october month.

Answer (score 212):

Some answers don't quite solve the issue. They print the date formatted as mm/dd/yyyy but the question was regarding MM/dd/yyyy. Notice the subtle difference? MM indicates that a leading zero must pad the month if the month is a single digit, thus having it always be a double digit number.

i.e. whereas mm/dd would be 3/31, MM/dd would be 03/31.

I've created a simple function to achieve this. Notice that the same padding is applied not only to the month but also to the day of the month, which in fact makes this MM/DD/yyyy:

```js
function getFormattedDate(date) {
  var year = date.getFullYear();

  var month = (1 + date.getMonth()).toString();
  month = month.length > 1 ? month : '0' + month;

  var day = date.getDate().toString();
  day = day.length > 1 ? day : '0' + day;
  
  return month + '/' + day + '/' + year;
}
```

---

*Update for ES2017 using String.padStart(), supported by all major browsers except IE.*

```js
function getFormattedDate(date) {
    let year = date.getFullYear();
    let month = (1 + date.getMonth()).toString().padStart(2, '0');
    let day = date.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');
  
    return month + '/' + day + '/' + year;
}
```

Comment: This is returning '2013/15/06' for 'Sat Jun 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Summer Time)'

Comment: I like this answer better than the chosen answer. However, leading "0"s should also be added to `year` to handle years that are less than 4 digits long.

Comment: Really consider using a library like Moment.js. It will format in desired result :)

Comment: @Ankur: instead copying your comment under each answer for the tip using Moment.js, you could give the code how it works with Moment.js..

Comment: I had trouble with this and found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929382/javascript-getfullyear-is-not-a-function from this I was able to get my answer below working.

Comment: function getFormattedDate(date) {
 var start = new Date(date);
 var year = start.getFullYear();

 var month = (1 + start.getMonth()).toString();
 month = month.length > 1 ? month : '0' + month;

 var day = start.getDate().toString();
 day = day.length > 1 ? day : '0' + day;
  
 return day + '/' + month + '/' + year;
}

Comment: you could also just use this to pad the numbers (see "2-digit" under month and day options).  This will also ensure your date format matches the user's locale:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat

Answer (score 61):

### ISO compliant *dateString*

If the ***dateString*** is [RFC282](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14) and [ISO8601](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/#sec-date.parse) compliant:
pass the string into the [Date Constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date).
Then, to format it into a desired date output use [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) like:

```js
const dateString = "2020-09-30T12:52:27+05:30"; // ISO8601 compliant dateString
const date = new Date(dateString); // {object Date}            

const dateFormatted = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", {
  year: "numeric",
  month: "2-digit",
  day: "2-digit"
}).format(date);

console.log(dateFormatted); // "09/30/2020"
```

alternatively, we can extract the desired values by using [Date Getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

```js
date.getMonth() + 1  // 9   (PS: use +1 since Month returns 0-based index)
date.getDate()       // 30
date.getFullYear()   // 2020
```

in the above example you might also want to use [String.prototype.padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) in order to add the leading zeros for month and date, if needed.

---

### Non-standard date string

If non-standard date string:
destructure the string into known parts, and then pass the variables to the [Date Constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date):

> **new Date**(*year, monthIndex [, day [, hours [, minutes [, seconds [, milliseconds]]]]]*)

```js
const dateString = "30/09/2020 12:52:27"; // Not ISO8601 compliant
const [d, M, y, h, m, s] = dateString.match(/\d+/g);

// PS: M-1 since Month is 0-based
const date = new Date(Date.UTC(y, M-1, d, h, m, s));  // {object Date}

const dateFormatted = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", {
  year: "numeric",
  month: "2-digit",
  day: "2-digit"
}).format(date);

console.log(dateFormatted); // "09/30/2020"
```

Comment: Really consider using a library like Moment.js. It will format in desired result :)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan How to convert "Month dd, yyyy" into "MM/dd/yyyy" in javascript?

Comment: Moment.js is *enormous* for simple stuff. Try date-format instead. Shaved 5 secs off my Webpack build time.

Comment: @EirikBirkeland nice suggestion. I abuse moment a lot for it's nice API and haven't even considered the amount of fluff.

Comment: This doesn't take into account timezones which could lead your date, month, and year to be wrong.

Comment: anyone else notice we're in 2022 and something as simple as managing a date in JS is still such a cluster - library or not.