# How to convert a date 2011-08-13T10:38:27 in dd /mm/yy format using javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I have a raw date appearing in the format 2011-08-13T10:38:27, I want this to be converted to the mm/dd/yy format using javascript and remove the extra values like time etc.

Is there any way to get the date in this format?

Thanks,
Ronan

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this [function](http://jsfiddle.net/E9guF/1/)

```
function formatDate(dateparam) {
    var dateObj = new Date(Date.parse(dateparam));

    var date = dateObj.getDate();
    date = (date.toString().length == 1) ? "0" + date : date;

    var month = dateObj.getMonth();
    month++;
    month = (month.toString().length == 1) ? "0" + month : month;

    var year = dateObj.getFullYear();

    return month + "/" + date + "/" + year;
}

document.write(formatDate("2011-08-13 05:38:27"));
// returns 08/13/2011
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the date very simply to a Date object by calling

```
var date = new Date("2011-08-13T10:38:27");
```

Then output it using

```
var dateString = (date.getMonth()+1).toString() + '/' + date.getDate().toString() + '/' +  date.getFullYear().toString();
```

Please read the previous posts before posting a new question. 
[Format date to MM/dd/yyyy in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591854/format-date-to-mm-dd-yyyy-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks for the solution Man but when I do: var date = new Date(2011-08-13T10:38:27); I get the value of date as Sat Aug 13 2011 16:08:27 GMT+0530 and then when i perform date.tostring("mm/dd/yy"), its values turns out to be an invalid date :(

Comment: +1 on parsing part... JavaScript does not support formatting strings - one need to construct it by hand or use some library for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var from = new Date(ur_date);</br>
var date =  " DATE('"+(from.getMonth()+1)+"-"+from.getDate()+"-"+from.getFullYear()+"')";</br>
```

Cheers...

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = new Date('2011-08-13T10:38:27');
alert((date.getMonth()+1).toString() + '/' + date.getDate().toString() + '/' +  date.getFullYear().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

use substr:

```
var dateyear="2011-08-13T10:38:27";
var year=dateyear.substr(0,dateyear.indexOf(-)-1);
var month=dateyear.substr(dateyear.indexOf(-)+1,dateyear.indexOf(-)+3)
var date=dateyear.substr(dateyear.indexOf(-)+4,dateyear.indexOf(-).length);

alert(month+"-"+date+"-"+year);
```