# Add date to filename when making copy

Tags: google-apps-script

I created a script to create a copy of a Gdoc:

```
// Script-as-app template.
function doGet(e) {
  //file has to be at least readable by the person running the script
  var fileId = e.parameters.fileId;  
  if(!fileId){
    //have a default fileId for testing. 
    fileId = '1TzLleN93A0ibMhSQ3eenZ1dLC3RLB7T9XoIaRw8-pfk'; 
  }
  var newUrl = DocsList.getFileById(fileId).makeCopy('Filename').getUrl(); 
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<h1><a href="'+newUrl+'">Open Document</a></h1>');
}
```

How would I go about adding today's date dd/mm/yy to the filename when running?

Answer (score 3):

### Get the old file name

I'd use **DriveApp** instead of **DocsList**.

```
var theFileReference = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
var oldFileName = theFileReference.getName();
```

### Create a variable for the new file name.

```
var d = new Date();
var curr_date = d.getDate();
var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();

var theDate = curr_date + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_year);

var newFileName = oldFileName + theDate;
```

### Make the copy:

```
theFileReference.makeCopy(newFileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var newUrl = DocsList.getFileById(fileId).makeCopy('Filename').getUrl();
```

The file name is set in the 'Filename' string above.

[Turning today's date into a string has been covered heaps of times.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591854/format-date-to-mm-dd-yyyy-in-javascript)