# Date string from Controller to JS using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

i wrote this controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetTrackList(POS_model item)
    {
        //item.item_code
        //item.track_type
        if (item.track_type != "Regular")
        {
            POS pos = new POS();
            DataTable dt = pos.GetTrackList(item.item_code, Convert.ToInt64(item.item_line_id), item.description, Convert.ToDouble(item.Qty), item.location, item.track_type);

            return Json(Utilities.GetTableRows(dt), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new {
                    required = "false"
            }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

and this script with ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetTrackList", "POS")',
            datatype: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify({ item_code: code, item_line_id: line_id, description: desc, Qty: qty, location: loc, track_type: t_type }),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                var table = document.getElementById("tblTrackList");
                $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                    var row = table.insertRow(-1);

                    var checked = row.insertCell(0);
                    var uid = row.insertCell(1);
                    var id = row.insertCell(2);
                    var transaction_code = row.insertCell(3);
                    var transaction_type = row.insertCell(4);
                    var item_line_id = row.insertCell(5);
                    var item_code = row.insertCell(6);
                    var item_codename = row.insertCell(7);
                    var item_description = row.insertCell(8);
                    var lot_number = row.insertCell(9);
                    var expiry_date = row.insertCell(10);
                    var qty = row.insertCell(11);
                    var available_qty = row.insertCell(12);
                    var bin_code = row.insertCell(13);
                    var is_draft = row.insertCell(14);
                    var entity_id = row.insertCell(15);

                    $(checked).html(item["checked"].toString());
                    $(uid).html(item["uid"]);
                    $(id).html(item["id"]);
                    $(transaction_code).html(item["transaction_code"]);
                    $(transaction_type).html(item["transaction_type"]);
                    $(item_line_id).html(item["item_line_id"]);
                    $(item_code).html(item["item_code"]);
                    $(item_codename).html(item["item_codename"]);
                    $(item_description).html(item["item_description"]);
                    $(lot_number).html(item["lot_number"]);
                    $(expiry_date).html(item["expiry_date"]);
                    $(qty).html(item["qty"]);
                    $(available_qty).html(item["available_qty"]);
                    $(bin_code).html(item["bin_code"]);
                    $(is_draft).html(item["is_draft"]);
                    $(entity_id).html(item["entity_id"]);
                })
            },
            error: function (req, status, errorObj) {
                alert(errorObj.toString());
            }
        });
```

Screenshot Result:
[image]

values of `DataRable dt` in Controller:
[image]

in the images above, why are the `expiry_date` fields displayed incorrectly in the first image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `$(expiry_date).html(item["expiry_date"]);` to following code.

```
var date = new Date(parseInt(item["expiry_date"].substr(6)));
$(expiry_date).html(date);
```

if you want to format your date then you can also check [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591854/format-date-to-mm-dd-yyyy-in-javascript) answer to format date