# JavaScript convert long date format to mm/dd/yyy

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I have the following code to convert a long date format in JavaScript to mm/dd/yyyy. When newValu is "Date 2016-12-29T00:00:00.000Z" from console log, date_str go back one day, becomes "12/28/2016". Not sure what is causing the problem. If we increment the d (day) by 1, that will not work, because we might need to increment the month instead, if d = 31.

```
                        console.log(newValue);
                        var date = newValue;
                        var d = date.getDate();
                        var m = date.getMonth() + 1;
                        var y = date.getFullYear();
                        date_str =  (m<=9 ? '0' + m : m) + '/' + (d <= 9 ? '0' + d : d) + "/" + y;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format date to MM/dd/yyyy in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591854/format-date-to-mm-dd-yyyy-in-javascript)

Comment: What is *newValue*, a string or Date object?

Answer (score 0):

Here a tip:

```
    function change(date) {
        var r = String(date).match(/^\s*([0-9]+)\s*-\s*([0-9]+)\s*-\s*([0-9]+)(.*)$/);
        return r[2] + "-" + r[3] + "-" + r[1] + r[4];
    }
```

This function will return a "mm/dd/yyyy".

Answer (score 0):

> Not sure what is causing the problem.

If *newValue* is a Date object and when printed to the console you get "2016-12-29T00:00:00.000Z", note that that is **GMT**.

If the host system has a time zone west of GMT (say -0400) then the equivalent date will be "2016-12-28T20:00:00.000Z", i.e. 4 hours earlier (and on the previous day). When you use plain *get* methods (*getDate*, *getHours*, *getMinutes*, etc.), it's these values you're getting.

So your date string is correct for the time zone of the host system.

```js
var x = new Date('2016-12-29T00:00:00.000Z');

// Local equivalent on your host system
document.write(x);

// UTC values in ISO 8601 format
document.write('<br>' + x.toISOString());

// Date string from ISO parts
document.write('<br>'+ ('0'+(x.getUTCMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '-' +
               ('0'+x.getUTCDate()).slice(-2) + '-'  +
               x.getUTCFullYear() );
```

If you want the values in your date string to match the UTC values of the Date object, then use UTC methods:

```
var d = date.getUTCDate();
var m = date.getUTCMonth() + 1;
var y = date.getUTCFullYear();
```