# TypeError: $.fn.dataTable.moment is not a function

Tags: jquery, datatable, momentjs

I'm using jquery DataTable plugin and in one of my tables, I wanted to sort the result based on the date time column. So, I included moment.js version 2.13.0 and my dataTable version is 1.10.10 and my jQuery version is 1.9.1.

As suggested in this latest dataTable date time sorting plugin article https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18, I tried the following but in the console I have

```
TypeError: $.fn.dataTable.moment is not a function
$.fn.dataTable.moment('DD-MMM-Y HH:mm:ss');
```

in my html page,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.fn.dataTable.moment('DD-MMM-Y HH:mm:ss');
    $('#myTable').DataTable();
} );
```

My Date column data has date in this format, `09-May-2016 19:38:00`. And I have interchanged the order in which the dataTable and moment.js plugin source is included in my html page. But I still get the same error. What could be the issue?

Comment: Did you import the _date / time sorting plug-in_ as suggested in the article you linked? You have to import: `//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.11/sorting/datetime-moment.js`

Comment: @VincenzoC yes I tried adding that js too.  I tried including it locally n also the CDN version. I get the same error message

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Browser cache issue. The JS files that I included are not properly downloaded in the browser causing the issue. I cleared the cache and used the CDN version. And it worked fine.
Here's my working code if anyone needs in future,

JS imports:

```
<script th:src="@{/js/jquery-1.8.3.js}" />
<script th:src="@{/js/jquery.datatables.min.js}" />
<script th:src="@{//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.min.js}" />
<script th:src="@{//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.11/sorting/datetime-moment.js}" />
```

DataTable init:

```
$(document).ready( function () {

    $.fn.dataTable.moment('DD-MMM-Y HH:mm:ss');

    $('#jobcardsTable').DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        "order": [[ 2, "desc" ]]
    });

});
```

So when initially the datatable loads the custom formatted date is parsed from the third column using moment.js and sorted in descending order.

Comment: Is the format applied on your table? For me it's not working.

Comment: My code (not working):  $('#tblResults').dataTable({
                    "columnDefs": [
                        { targets: [5, 6], render: $.fn.dataTable.moment("DD.MM.YYYY") }                        
                    ],

Comment: @FrenkyB It works fine for me. Could you make a jsfiddle demo of your code or a new question and link it here?

Comment: @FrenkyB Again, works fine for me. Check this fiddle, that I created now based on your fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/kn8xu10w/4/  The date column is automcatically sorted in descending order. change the value to `asc` if you want to sort in ascending order. Important thing is you should make sure the datatables version is `1.10.x`. It works even without formatting the date.

Comment: Yes, sorting works, thanks for fiddle. Perhaps you know how to change formatting of the date column to DD.MM.YYYY ?

Comment: @FrenkyB Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591854/format-date-to-mm-dd-yyyy-in-javascript it shoud help.

Comment: Thanks again. It's not a problem to format a date - my only problem is how to format the date in the jquery datatable. I don't know how to do this... I thought that your solution also formats dates, not only sorts.

Comment: My code above only sorts the datatable column in date format. It does not format the date. You should do it in your rendering engine or server side.

Answer (score 29):

The order of importing the scripts is important. **You have to include datatables before the sorting plugin**. The following works for me:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.12/sorting/datetime-moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 10):

The two files below are required;

- `moment.min.js`, and
- `datetime-moment.js`

Do load all files in the following order:

- Moment,
- DateTables,
- DataTables + Moment plug-in.