# Sort DataTable by dd/MM/yyyy format

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, model-view-controller, datatable

Indices 6, 7 and 8 in my datatable contain dates
The date in the database looks like this: 2024-02-22 00:00:00.000

**jquery-datatable.js codes;**

```
$(function () {
        $('.tum-cihaz-listesi').DataTable({
            initComplete: function () {
                var api = this.api();
                var footers = $('tfoot th');
                for (i = 0; i < footers.length; i++) {
                    api.order.listener(footers[i], i);
                }
            },
            responsive: true,
            pageLength: 50,
            paging: true,
            ordering: true,
            info: true,
            dom: '<"top"lfB>rt<"bottom"ip>',
            buttons: [
                'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'print',
                {
                    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                    text: 'Portrait PDF',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: ':visible', orthogonal: 'print'
                    }
                },
                {
                    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                    text: 'Landscape PDF',
                    orientation: 'landscape',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: ':visible', orthogonal: 'print'
                    }
                }
            ],
            columnDefs: [
                { type: 'datetime-moment', targets: [6, 7, 8] }
            ]
        });
```

**MVC | Views code;**

```
<td>
    @if (item.INVENTORY_DETAILs.InstallDate.HasValue)
        {@item.INVENTORY_DETAILs.InstallDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")}
    else
    {
    }
</td>
<td>
    @if (item.INVENTORY_DETAILs.CalibrationCareDate.HasValue)
        {@item.INVENTORY_DETAILs.CalibrationCareDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")}
    else
    {
    }
</td>
<td>
    @if (item.INVENTORY_DETAILs.CalibrationValidateDate.HasValue)
        {@item.INVENTORY_DETAILs.CalibrationValidateDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")}
    else
    {
    }
</td>
```

**I may be a bit of an amateur about it. Sorting by date, there is an error, it does not sort by date, it sorts by string, for example, it sorts as follows: 29 - 30 - 31 or 31 - 30 - 29**

I try

BlackBox.ai
ChatGPT
DataTable docs and more...

Comment: Can you just populate the datatable with the date values, rather than calling `ToString()`?

Comment: I tried this too, but to no avail. Here's what it looks like: https://prnt.sc/RxGDb0iLWFo7

Comment: Stack Trace: datetime-moment.js:28 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at datetime-moment.js:28:11
    at datetime-moment.js:30:2
(anonim) @ datetime-moment.js:28
(anonim) @ datetime-moment.js:30
TumCihazListesi:21385 tr
jquery-datatable.js:71 Uncaught TypeError: $.fn.dataTable.moment is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (jquery-datatable.js:71:24)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2:27449)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2:28213)
    at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2:30006)
    at HTMLDocument.K (jquery.min.js:2:30368)

Comment: [TypeError: $.fn.dataTable.moment is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37118273/typeerror-fn-datatable-moment-is-not-a-function) - _"I'm using jquery DataTable plugin and in one of my tables, I wanted to sort the result based on the date time column..."_

Comment: If you are fetching data from your backend, why don't you sort there?  Have you tried that? Or you are getting data from another API where you don't have control on?

Comment: I have multiple date values in my multiple tables that I need to sort on, I don't know how to do it on the backend without using sort in the table.