# How to convert String mm/dd/yyyy to Date mm/dd/yyyy using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

Please find the snippet with issues below

```
var date = new Date('9/14/2016');
alert((date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + (date.getDate()+20) + '/' + date.getFullYear());
```

[image]

On adding 20 days from the current date, it should display expected result as shown in the above image. Currently, the inserted data is not parsed as Date format to get the exact output. any work around on this?

Comment: Give a visit here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591854/format-date-to-mm-dd-yyyy-in-javascript

Comment: The title seems to be wrong, you seem to want to add days to a date, not convert it to something.

Comment: Okay; actually its not a duplicate question

Comment: just now noticed; however the issue got solved. May be this will help other for sure :)

Comment: @PrashanthSams—actually, it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
var date = new Date('12/14/2016'); 
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 20); // add 20 days 
alert((date.getMonth()+1) + '/' + (date.getDate()) + '/' + date.getFullYear()); // output
```

Comment: "*You can't add days by simply adding 20 to the current date.*". That is exactly what you're doing. You need to add 1 to the value returned by *getMonth* as the month number is zero indexed.

Comment: @TomasLangkaas Yes, it is wrong answer. let me try the suggested link

Comment: Made changes in the answer; it should work as of now