# Converting dates in YYYY-MM-DD to DD-MONTH in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, string, date

I have the following dates as strings..

```
2016-10-14
2016-10-15
2016-10-16
2016-10-17
2016-10-18
2016-10-19
2016-10-20
```

How can I dynamically convert them to the following in JavaScript?

```
14 Oct
15 Oct
16 Oct
...
```

Comment: have a look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591854/format-date-to-mm-dd-yyyy-in-javascript, and its a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript

Comment: use the javascript `Date` type object

Comment: @JaromandaX—there is no need to use a Date.

Comment: True @RobG - but there's no reason not to either (I know, there's a dozen reasons not to, because javascript dates make the baby jesus cry)

Comment: @JaromandaX—there are many reasons not to, the best is that it is easier (fewer cross–implementation issues, no Date issues) to create a robust function without it. The first four answers here depend on inconsistent parsing and implementation dependent methods, some produce the wrong results in all hosts, others will produce wrong results in at least some hosts.

Comment: I did add that there are a dozen reasons not to use Date :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
results=[]
string=['2016-10-14', '2016-10-15', '2016-10-16', '2016-10-17', '2016-10-18', '2016-10-19', '2016-10-20']
for(var i=0;i<string.length;++i){
  date=new Date(string[i]);
  list=date.toUTCString().split( " ")
results.push(list[1]+" "+list[2])
}


console.log(results)
```

Comment: The value returned by *toUTCString* is implementation dependent, there is no reason for the above to return the required result in all implementations.

Answer (score 1):

```
var dates = ['2016-10-14', '2016-10-15', '2016-10-16', '2016-10-17', '2016-10-18', '2016-10-19', '2016-10-20'];

function convertDates(str) {
  var d = new Date(str);
  var day = d.getDate();
  var month = d.toString().split(' ')[1];
  return day +' '+ month;
}

var final = [];

dates.map(function(item) {
  final.push(convertDates(item)); 
});
```

That's it!

Comment: This will parse the string to a date then create an implementation dependent string that is then reformatted to another string. Why not just reformat the original string?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a Date object, and certainly you should not parse strings with the Date constructor.

Note that:

```
new Date('2016-10-14')
```

will return a date for 13 October for users with a time zone west of Greenwich.

Just reformat the string:

```js
/* Reformat a date like 2016-10-14 as dd MMM
** @param {string} s - date string to reformat
** @returns {string}
*/
function formatDDMMM(s) {
  var months = 'Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec'.split(' ');
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return b[2] + ' ' + months[b[1]-1];
}

console.log(formatDDMMM('2016-10-14'));
```