# How to display Json date string as DD/MM/YYYY in a table

Tags: javascript, json, date, datetime

I'm trying to format some json dates in a table to a more readable format.  The string returned from the json looks like this `"2015-06-29T10:00:00.000Z"`.

The time is not important, I just want to show the date as dd/mm/yyyy.

I have tried using `new date(detestring)` but i might have got this wrong, as its not working.  Here is the full code.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
 $.getJSON( 'opp.php', function(data) { 
  $.each(data.opportunities, function() { 
   $("table#outtodaytomorrow").append("<tr><td>" + this.number + "</td><td>" + new Date(this.starts_at) + "</td></tr>");
});
});
});
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Try `moment.js`

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [*Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript?s=1|13.3026) or [*How to format a JavaScript date*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date?s=2|3.9424).

Answer (score 2):

You have to create your own function which achieve your target.

```
function formatDate(stringDate){
    var date=new Date(stringDate);
    return date.getDate() + '/' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' +  date.getFullYear();
}
```

Your code:

```
$("table#outtodaytomorrow").append("<tr><td>" + this.number + "</td><td>" + formatDate(this.starts_at) + "</td></tr>");
```

Comment: @Alexandru-lonut Perfect, that was just that i was looking for.  I see how it works now. Thanks.

Comment: I spoke too soon, this does not seem to work, and just produces some error.  unless I am calling the function incorrectly

Comment: Function names starting with a capital letter are, by convention, reserved for constructors. `this.starts_at` is a string, calling Date methods on a string won't work, you need to convert it to a Date beforehand.

Comment: @RobG, thanks for your point!. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

See [Format date to MM/dd/yyyy in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591854/format-date-to-mm-dd-yyyy-in-javascript)

First, parse it to a date with

```
var date = new Date(this.starts_at);
```

Second, print your date as desired

```
var dateStr = (date.getDate() + '/' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' +  date.getFullYear())
```

You will get `"6/29/2015"`

For your specific instance, it would be something like

```
 $(document).ready( function() {
   $.getJSON( 'opp.php', function(data) { 
     $.each(data.opportunities, function() { 
       var date = new Date(this.starts_at);
       var dateStr = (date.getDate() + '/' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' +  date.getFullYear())
       $("table#outtodaytomorrow").append("<tr><td>" + this.number + "</td><td>" + dateStr + "</td></tr>");
     });
   });
 });
```

Breaking up the component into different pieces of memory such as "date" and "dateStr" makes it easier to read and understand.

Comment: Great, thanks Zak.  This looks like just what I was after.  It might be a stupid question, but how would I go about adding this into my code so that it works for each line of the table?

Comment: @James,please take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [MomentJs](https://momentjs.com/docs/) to parse the first input and then format it to your desired format. 
Something like :

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$.getJSON( 'opp.php', function(data) { 
    $.each(data.opportunities, function() { 
        $("table#outtodaytomorrow").append("<tr><td>" + this.number + "</td><td>" + moment(this.starts_at).format("DD/MM/YYYY") + "</td></tr>");
    });
});
});
```

Comment: This can be done in native javascript in 2 lines. 1 if you're crafty enough. No need to import an unnecessary library.

Comment: Everythings can be done in native javascript. The point here is to save time and make the code cleaner.