# Angular Material table, how to filter a Date of type moment.Moment

Tags: javascript, angular, date, angular-material, momentjs

I have a mat-table and a search field, where I Filter the results.

The dataSource variable is populated by a nested object, so I had to setup a `filterPredicate` to make the filter work on the nested object properties.

Everything works, but I also have a field that is for a date.

The date I retrieve is of type `moment.Moment` and looks like this:

```
date: Moment
_d: Sat Sep 22 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0200 {}
_i: "2018-9-22"
_isAMomentObject: true
_isUTC: false
_isValid: true
_locale: Locale {_calendar: {…}, _longDateFormat: {…}, _invalidDate: "Invalid date", _ordinal: "%d.", _dayOfMonthOrdinalParse: /\d{1,2}\./, …}
_pf: {empty: false, unusedTokens: Array(0), unusedInput: Array(0), overflow: -2, charsLeftOver: 0, …}
__proto__: Object
```

The sort works on this date, I Can sort the date column without issue, but when I type in the filter, I can't filter out by using the date, which is piped in the html like this:

```
{{element.date | date : "shortDate"}}
```

so what can I do to being able to filter the dates by how they are displayed in the table with this pipe?

Thank you

edit: filter code:

```
nestedFilterCheck(search, data, key): any {
        if (typeof data[key] === "object") {
            for (const k in data[key]) {
                if (data[key][k] !== null) {
                    search = this.nestedFilterCheck(search, data[key], k);
                }
            }
        } else {
            search += data[key];
        }
        return search;
    }

this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data, filter: string) => {
                const accumulator = (currentTerm, key) => {
                    return this.nestedFilterCheck(currentTerm, data, key);
                };
                const dataStr = Object.keys(data)
                    .reduce(accumulator, "")
                    .toLowerCase();
                const transformedFilter = filter.trim().toLowerCase();
                return dataStr.indexOf(transformedFilter) !== -1;
            };

applyFilter(filterValue: string): void {
        filterValue = filterValue.trim();
        filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase();
        this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
    }

 <input matInput #filter (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)">
```

Comment: Create a date pipe in your component logic. Let me redirect you to one of my previous answers on that matter : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48183677/how-to-format-date-in-component-of-angular-5/48183927#48183927

Comment: By using a pipe in your control, you'll be able to use the pipe programmatically, meaning you will be able to filter on the displayed date rather than the real value of the date.

Comment: The issue with this is that when I try to pipe my date property before passing it to the dataSource in my controller, it gives error because that pipe returns a string, and my date property is a moment Object! How can I solve this?

Comment: You don't pass your updated date to your table : you only use the pipe in the filter. If your value is an instance of moment date, then you pipe it to get a string, and compare your input value to that string. Sorry if that wasn't clear !

Comment: As a piece of advice, pipes are used to edit the **displayed data**. You don't use them to transform your data !

Comment: where should I pipe it in the filter? updating my OP with the filter code in a sec

Comment: Simply create a pipe in your function and use the `.transform` method : instead of sending your element value, you send `pipe.transform(element.momentDate, 'shortDate')` !

Comment: not sure I got it, so in my component I do this: pipe = new DatePipe("en-US");
then in my html file I do this: 

*matCellDef="let element">{{pipe.transform(element.date, 'shortDate')}}</td>

this doesn't affect my data, if I console.log my dataSource, the date will be the same, what I want to achieve is, the displayed date in the table is in this format: DD.MM.YY, and I want to be able to filter it by typing the same format in the serach field, currently if I want to filter the date I need to follow moment's format which is YYYY-M-DD, and this works in the filter field

Comment: Component : `pipe = new DatePipe("en-US")`, template : `*matCellDef="let element">{{ element.date | date:'shortDate' }}</td>`, in your filter function : `inputValue === this.pipe.transform(element.date, 'shortDate')`. You simply compare your input value to the **transformed value of your element date with the pipe**. That's all it is used for !

Comment: ok all clear besides which one is the right filter function that I need to add the pipe check? I added in my OP all the filter functions I have, applyFilter() is on (keyup), filterPredicate is used because I have some nested objects I need to access, and nestedFilterCheck() is used in the filterPredicate.

So where exactly should I put inputValue === this.pipe.transform(element.date, 'shortDate') ? thank you for the help

Comment: Where you test for the equality. If you have a full text search (one field for all columns), you can use `if (elementValue instanceof moment.Moment)`, otherwise if you have a dedicated field, you should check this here.

Comment: I only have one field for filter every column of my data, as you can see above, it's the <input> tag where I have the (keyup), so that's why I don't really understand where should I check for the istance of moment and pipe the value, I wrote above every function that I have for the filtering and it's all done in a single <input>, sorry but first time I work with mat-tables

Comment: We're drifting too much there : I made a stackblitz to explain how it works : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nnvasd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts see how the date given matches ? That's because the **piped date** is compared to the value, not the *actual date object*. Is it clear with this ?

Comment: I probably explained myself poorly! the logic behind was clear since your first post! I got that I need to pipe my element before comparing it to the input string, so I don't compare the input string with a moment object! What I'm having trouble understanding, is where to put the logic! I saw your stackblitz, you create a filter function, but you access your elements and filter them there, should I do the same with "this.dataSource" ? because my elements (included the moment Object) are in "this.dataSource". That's why I wrote above my code so you could help me out with my specific scenario

Comment: I m not sure if I can just add a line of code for the pipe check in my current code, or if I do need to rewrite a new filter function like your stack blitz, and in that case, should I pass the dataSource directly into it?

Comment: Oh okay sorry ! At this point it's more of a personal preference and good practice question : I would say that you should favorize the "externalized" solutions, which is creating functions : those functions can then be re-used elsewhere, while "inner functions" are bound to a specific use-case and can't be re-used. And for the datasource, I would have used an Observable, not a variable, but as a good practice, you should keep your data away from the datasource, and not filter on the datasource itself, but do `this.datasource = new MatTableDatasource(filteredData)` !

Comment: ok thank you very much for your help