# Angular 2 - howto insert html element with translate pipe from component

Tags: angular

In `.html` file I have:

```
<div id="container">
</div>
```

I want to add a `button` inside it, with some text which should be translated.

I can do It like this:

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var button = document.createElement('button');
button.innerText = this.translate.instant('SOME_TEXT');
container.appendChild(button);
```

Problem here is that this `SOME_TEXT` will be translated only one time. If language will change while this button is displayed - text won't change.

I would like to make something like:

```
button.innerHTML = `{{'DONE' | translate}}`;
```

, where `translate` is `translate: TranslateService,` in `constructor`, and I do `import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';`

Is it possible?

Comment: Why should you create your button on this way. Is there no way to add it directly to the element?

Comment: if `translate` is not a built-in pipe then you have to create custom pipe

Comment: @Bo I need to hack a library to add button dynamicaly into a popup

Comment: Feel free to check my answer about pipes in components : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48183677/how-to-format-date-in-component-of-angular-5/48183927#48183927

Comment: @ashish `translate` is from `@ngx-translate/core`, I'll add this to question. Problem is it doesn't work like this, it will just insert string `"{{'DONE' | translate}}"` into html.

Comment: @trichetriche I don't want to USE pipe in component. I would like to PASS a pipe from component to html file.

Comment: That's either using a pipe in a component, or creating a pipe. `PASS a pipe from component to html file` doesn't mean anything.

Comment: @trichetriche I'll try to be more clear - you can do something like `<button>{{'DONE' | translate}</button>` in `html` file. I would like to insert a button from `ts` file, which will behave just like this one.

Comment: So through innerHTML ?

Comment: I tried it already, as given in the example.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
export class CashMovementListComponent {
  constructor(private translate: TranslateService) { 
     ... 
     button.innerHTML = this.translate.instant('LABEL.AMOUNT_TOPAY');
  }
}
```