# Send data from pipe to component using @Inject(forwardRef(())

Tags: angular, filter, pipe

I am trying to send a filtered array from my pipe to my component, using `@Inject(forwardRef(())` like this:

filter.pipe.ts

```
constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => OpenItemsComponent)) private ded_open: OpenItemsComponent) {}
transform(items: any[], field: string, value: string[]): any[] {
    ...
    this.ded_open.filteredData(this.newArray)
    ...
}
```

app.ts

```
...
filteredData(val) {
    this.currentFilter = val.slice()
    console.log(this.currentFilter) // in currentFilter I will have the filtered array
...
```

}

What I am trying to to, is injecting more components, because I use this pipe in 4 components. And I tried something like this:

```
constructor(
@Inject(forwardRef(() => OpenItemsComponent)) private ded_open: OpenItemsComponent,
@Inject(forwardRef(() => ClosedItemsComponent)) private ded_closed: ClosedItemsComponent,
@Inject(forwardRef(() => TrdIComponent)) private trade_open: TradeInvoicesComponent,
@Inject(forwardRef(() => TrdIClosedComponent)) private trade_closed: TradeInvoicesClosedComponent) {
  }
```

but I get

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[FilterPipe -> ClosedItemsComponent]: 
>     StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[FilterPipe -> ClosedItemsComponent]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for ClosedItemsComponent!

I can't inject more components inside pipe constructor? How can I solve this? Thank you for your time!

(P.S - I know using pipes is bad, but this is just for a demo, not the final version)

Comment: Pipes are used to transform the value **to display it**. It shouldn't change your value. If it does, consider doing your pipe transformation directly into your component. As a sidenote, I'll let you check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48183677/how-to-format-date-in-component-of-angular-5/48183927#48183927) that shows how you can create pipe instances in your components.

Comment: I just want to send the filter from pipe to component and this is the way I did.. but it's working only with a component, not with 4, and I don't know why. I can't afford to modify my pipe right now, I am in a hurry. But thank you anyway.

Comment: Again, you should not do that. That's not what they're used for. Instead , as said, declare a pipe instance in your component and use its `transform` method.

Comment: you could use a service which you inject in both your components and your pipe. (no idea, if it that really works with change detection and everything)
But again, it's misusing pipes. Even for a demo.

But why not change your pipe to a component and use an `@Output` property?