# show date (DD-MM-YYY) format in chartist tool-tip plugin?

Tags: javascript, chartist.js

There is implementation of chartist tool tip plugin in a chartist, I like to know is it possible to change the date format to human readable as such DD-MM-YYYY.

```
    var chart = new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', {
  labels: [1, 2, 3],
  series: [
    [
      {meta: 'description', x :new Date(parseInt(15433865410)), y: 25},

    ],
  ]
}, {
  plugins: [
    Chartist.plugins.tooltip()
  ]
});
```

In tooltip the x axis value shows as 15433865410, I need it to be DD-MM-YYYY. Any suggestion appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591854/format-date-to-mm-dd-yyyy-in-javascript

Comment: This is Chartist way of implementation. So, I need to call the function inside the chartist tool tip plugin. Which makes me confusing. I read the docs before positing the question. @just

Comment: I think you can't put an string in `x` value of your code it will be always take an integer so you can't convert it into `dd-mm-yyyy`.

Comment: I know that @ShubhamBaranwal, because it wont plot the value, that why we should change the value inside the tooltip() function

Answer (score 0):

You can't put an `string` value in x because it always takes an `integer`. But you can write in `meta` in date format `dd-mm-yyyy`. Here's my code -

```
var chart = new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', {
  labels: [1, 2, 3],
  series: [
    [
      {meta: dateConvert(15433865410)+', '+ 25, x:new Date(parseInt(15433865410)), y: 25},

    ],
  ]
}, {
  plugins: [
    Chartist.plugins.tooltip()
  ]
});

function dateConvert(dateString){
  dateStr = new Date(parseInt(dateString));
  dateStr = dateStr.getDate() + '-' + ("0" + (dateStr.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + dateStr.getFullYear();
  return dateStr;
}
```