# Transform date to DD/MM/YY

Tags: javascript, date, time

I get the date from server in such format: 2019-01-24 00:00:00

How to convert it to 24-01-2019?

I use:

```
new Date(dateFromServer).toLocaleDateString()
```

but it returns 01/24/19.

Comment: var d = new Date(dateFromServer);
var datestring =   (d.getMonth()+1) +  "/" + d.getDate() + '/' +d.getFullYear()

Comment: @DeepakSingh - month/day/year is what OP is already getting ... your suggestion results in a less correct answer, because it doesn't even have the leading 0 in the month ... OP wants dd-mm-yyyy

Answer (score 0):

as seen here [Format date to MM/dd/yyyy in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591854/format-date-to-mm-dd-yyyy-in-javascript)

```
var date = new Date(dateFromServer);
alert(date.getDate() + '-' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' +  date.getFullYear());
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid answers that suggest parsing, it doesn't make sense to parse a string to a Date and reformat it just to get back the values you started with, given the risks of using the built–in parser (e.g. in Safari, `new Date('2019-01-24 00:00:00')` returns an invalid Date).

To reformat a date, just split it into the parts and put it back as you want:

```js
// @param {string} s - timestamp in format YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss
function reformatDateString(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return `${b[1]}/${b[2]}/${b[0]}`
}

console.log(reformatDateString('2019-01-24 00:00:00'));
```