# how to get date value as (MM-DD-YYYY) from date picker in JS

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

When I pick the value from the date picker input its in this format (Tue Mar 24 2020 17:00:00 GMT-0800(PST) I need to convert it to (MM-DD-YYYY)

Here is the part from my code where I get the value of the date

```
Reportinfo.ProjectDate = document.getElementById("date").value;
```

Any Ideas ? I didn't know how to implement

```
"toLocaleDateString()"
```

Comment: Have you tried to use momentjs ? Something like this moment(yourDate).format('MM-DD-YYYY')

Answer (score 2):

You can use [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) and format the string like this:

```
moment(date).format('MM-DD-YYYY');
```

Or if that's not an option, you can use `Date` object and use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11591900/3930247).