# Format and change date

Tags: javascript, date, formatting

I am getting a date formatted this way:

```
18th February
```

And after adding weeks, should come back in the same format
example:

```
input => 18th February + 7 weeks:

output => 31st March
```

I am able to get the date and add weeks but I am finding very complicate to format the date back.

This is what I have right now:

```
let date = new Date(("18th February").replace(/st|rd|nd|th/g, ""))

let weeks = 7 * 7

let newDate = date.setDate(date.getDate() + weeks)

console.log(new Date(newDate))

//Output

2001-03-31T23:00:00.000Z

//Desire Output

//31st March
```

Thank you for you help.

Comment: Probably you are searching this- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591854/format-date-to-mm-dd-yyyy-in-javascript

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think date formatting in the Front-End isn't really good so libraries always help (like momentjs, datefnz, etc..)

But you could add this to your code to make it work:

```
let date = new Date(("18th February").replace(/st|rd|nd|th/g, ""))

let weeks = 7 * 7

let newDate = new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() + weeks))

let months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
let month = months[newDate.getMonth()]
let day = newDate.getDate()

function dayWithNth (d) {
  if (d > 3 && d < 21) return `${d}th`;
  switch (d % 10) {
    case 1:  return `${d}st`;
    case 2:  return `${d}nd`;
    case 3:  return `${d}rd`;
    default: return `${d}th`;
  }
}

console.log(`${dayWithNth(day)} ${month}`)
```

Comment: `new Date(("18th February")` should be strongly discouraged, it produces an invalid Date in at least one current browser.

Comment: That's true, thanks for pointing that out.

I actually just used his code and added 1 way to get the format Mario wanted.

Cheers.