# Display date (<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>;) to input when button is click - JQuery JS PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Good Day Everyone,

I would like to seek your help in displaying the current date to input type"date" when button is click.
format is like this  or mm/dd/yyyy. thank you

```js
$(function() {
  $('#btncheckout').click(function() {
    var time = new Date();
    $('subdateout').val(time.toDateString());
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="input-group-sm mb-3 row align-middle ">
  <input type="date" name="subdateout" id="subdateout" class="form-control rounded-0 w3-tiny" max="<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>" value="">
</div>

<div class="col-sm-3">
  <button type="button" id="btncheckout" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm rounded-0">Check Out</button>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: You are missing `#` near `$('subdateout')...`

Comment: @Swati corrected it Sir/Maam, got this output "Thu May 13 2021"

Comment: You can format that date check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591854/format-date-to-mm-dd-yyyy-in-javascript) post to do same .

Comment: @Swati appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a down and dirty way to get it into the format you want.

```js
var time = new Date();
var datestring = ("0"+(time.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + "/" + ( "0" + time.getDate()).slice(-2) + "/" + 
    time.getFullYear() 

console.log(datestring)
```

Taken from this amazing collection of date format options. [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: appreciate the help @John Tyner

Comment: If this helped or is the solution, please upvote and/or accept as the answer. Thanks