# Passing a string to new Date() constructor results in Invalid Date

Tags: javascript, date

How can I pass a string date from a variable to the `new Date(...)` constructor? The following code produces `Invalid Date`. Do I need to convert it first somehow?

```js
var dateString = '18/11/2021';
var dateObject = new Date(dateString);
alert(dateObject);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format date to MM/dd/yyyy in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591854/format-date-to-mm-dd-yyyy-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

When using the `Date(dateString)` constructor, the date string must be specified in [simplified ISO 8601 date format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#date_time_string_format). Also note that conforming date only formats such as `yyyy-mm-dd` are treated as UTC, not local. The following should produce the expected result:

```js
alert(new Date("2021-11-18T00:00:00"));
```

Using any non-standard format is discouraged and the results are implementation specific.

Comment: [Relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1179/)

Answer (score 0):

it's your dateString format. First the year, month and then day.

```js
hello = '2021/11/18';
end = new Date(hello);
alert(end);
```