# Format Date in Google App Script to YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I'm trying to format the date in Google App Script and then store it into the Google Sheet. Everything is working fine but the problem is source date has no specific format, dates may come in different formats like **DD-MM-YYYY, MM-DD-YYYY, YYYY-MM-DD** or date can also come with time and then I've to convert it into **YYYY-MM-DD** format and then save in google sheet.
I've tried to convert to covert using the below codes:

```
var date = new Date("01-15-2022").toISOString().split('T')[0] // MM/dd/yyyy
Logger.log(date);
```

this code works only if the source date has in a format like **MM/dd/yyyy** and **yyyy/MM/dd** only if the date is in a format like **dd/MM/yyyy** then codes does not work.

I want a method that converts all the date formats in a single format like **yyyy/MM/dd**

Comment: Consider using [`Intl.DateTimeFormat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat) instead?

Comment: @evolutionxbox, how to use YYYY-MM-DD format inside this function?

Comment: `new Date('2022-01-15')` works, but `new Date('01-15-2022')` is an invalid date since Date cannot parse `MM-DD-YYYY`

Comment: @evolutionxbox, that's why here I'm asking to convert any format into `yyyy-MM-dd` format.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format date to MM/dd/yyyy in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591854/format-date-to-mm-dd-yyyy-in-javascript) - use `Intl` for the output, but it should help you parse any date.

Comment: "*source date has no specific format, dates may come in different formats*" then you're stuffed. You can only reliably parse a timestamp if you know the format, or it's unambiguous (e.g. use the month name). Otherwise, you're asking for an unachievable result.

Comment: This https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/100644

Answer (score 3):

I got a little bad news for you. There is no way to distinguish algorithmically between  `01-02-2022` (Feb 1, 2022) and `01-02-2022` (Jan 2, 2022). So technically this source data is the infamous 'garbage in'.

Comment: Is any way through which we can know the difference between day and month. If the day is lesser than 12 (month)?

Comment: Of course you can parse some dates since we have 12 month only. Do you need it? Do you need help to figure out this partial solution? It’s a set of quite trivial tricks. (But there will be troubles again as soon as you come across the dates with YY like ‘21-10-22’)

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I managed to find an alternative option to achieve this using Moment Js Library below is the solution:

```
function myFunction() {
  let formats = ["DD/MM/YYYY", "MM/DD/YYYY", "YYYY/MM/DD", "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss", "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss A", "MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss A", "YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm:ss A"]
  Logger.log(convertDate("5/1/2022 12:00:00 PM", formats));
}


function convertDate(date, formats){
  eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js').getContentText());
  let dateMomentObject = moment(date, formats);
  let dateObject = dateMomentObject.toDate();
  let dateStr = moment(dateObject).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  return dateStr;
}
```

Comment: How does this determine between day first and month first?

Comment: @evolutionxbox, Yeah actually I'm getting this problem now, do you know any solution for this??

Comment: There is no way to distinguish. The data needs to be consistent.