# How to convert RFC 3339 datetime into regular JavaScript format

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I need to use the Google Calendar service for editing single instances of an event series. The service returns datetime values in RFC 3339 format (like `2022-11-03T21:30:41.043Z`), which is hard to process within Google apps script. Is there an easy way feeding it into `Utilities.formatDate` to convert it (ie `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm`)?

Vice versa is plainly done with `.toISOString()`.

Comment: This might have potentially been answered over here and probably a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591854/format-date-to-mm-dd-yyyy-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert an [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format date string into a JavaScript Date object directly with the Date constructor. To convert the Date object into a formatted date string, use `Utilities.formatDate()` with your preferred timezone, like this:

```js
function test() {
  const dateISO8601 = '2022-11-03T21:30:41.043Z';
  const timezone = 'PST';
  const dateString = toDateString_(dateISO8601, timezone);
  console.log(dateString);
}

function toDateString_(dateISO8601, timezone = 'GMT') {
  const date = new Date(dateISO8601);
  return Utilities.formatDate(date, timezone, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm');
}
```